# Modify the program to read dictionary items from a file and write the inverted dictionary to a file

Tags: python-3.x, file, dictionary

Modify the program to read dictionary items from a file and write the inverted dictionary to a file.The following applies:

1.Format each dictionary item as a text string in the input file.

2.Covert each input string into a dictionary item.

3.Format each item of the inverted dictionary as a text string in the output file.

Create an input file with your original three-or-more items and add at least three new items, for a total of at least six items.

'''

```
PW_dict = {
  'PassWord1': ['apple_ID","email@yahoo.com'],
  'Password2': ['yahoo_mail","example_login'],
  'Password3': ['google_mail","SteveJobs@me'],
  'Password4': ['facebook","email@yahoo.com'],
}


print("")


def invert(d):
  inverse = dict()
  for key in d:
    val = d[key]
    for item in val:
      if item not in inverse:
        inverse[item] = [key]
      else:
        inverse[item].append(key)
  return inverse 


inverted_PW_dict = invert(PW_dict)
print(inverted_PW_dict)
```

'''

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to covert the output of the dictionary to a file a and then add three new items to the file.